# When renting an apartment what does T4 stand for?

Tags: abréviations

What do T2, T3, T4, and T5 stand for? Does it mean the number of rooms?

Comment: This question is not exactly about the French language, but I have to confess I would really like to know the answer.

Comment: You have your answer, but I have to close this as not on topic for a site about "French Language & Usage."

Comment: Sorry, I posted it here because I've only ever seen the abbreviation since looking for an apartment in France.

Comment: @RobertCartaino FYI, I've reopened this question, because I don't see how it's off-topic: it's about the meaning of a French word. It's covered in French Wikipedia, but not in a way that's easy to follow if you're a non-native looking for an apartment in France, so I'm not comfortable closing as “general reference” either.

Comment: See also [T2 / F2 / F3 / … - Appartment size codes in France](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2849/t2-f2-f3-appartment-size-codes-in-france) on [expatriates.se]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The number counts the rooms where one can live: bedrooms and the (aptly named) living room; 'T' stands for 'type'. You can also find 'F' instead of 'T', there is no difference.

Rooms "for living" must fill some criteria to qualify as such: minimum area (I believe 9m²), a minimum height and a at least one window. If the room has no window (dark or open), or is too small, it doesn't count, and can only be advertised as a storage space (often called "cellier" or "loggia"). Also mandatory are a separate bathroom, and kitchen and toilets, both of which may or may not be separate from, respectively, a regular room and the bathroom.

You might in very rare cases also get a large "dark room" ("pièce aveugle"), without window, suitable to be used as a study/computer room, but which can only be advertised as a storage space. So a T1 might give you 4 rooms in total (bedroom, kitchen, bathroom, "storage space"). (I actually had a 60m² T2 with a similar arrangement--very comfy.)

Also, some "wide" living rooms (>20m²) will be advertised as two rooms. So a T3 might only get you 3 rooms (large living room with kitchen, bathroom, bedroom).

Note that a 'T1' and a 'studio' are not the same thing:

- TI : one kitchen, one bathroom, one room;
- Studio: one bathroom, kitchen and bedroom in the same space ("cuisine américaine").

Answer (score 8):

Yes it does.

To be more specific, this is the number of rooms in which you can live: the kitchen, the bathroom, the toilets are not included in that number, but only the rooms and the living and dining room(s). A "dressing" doesn't count either unless it meets the requirement of a "main room", [according to this article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appartement#Classification_des_logements).

This number should also include at least one room. For example you cannot have just a living room and a bathroom as a room is mandatory.

Comment: thanks. Do you happen to know what the letter T stands for?

Comment: T stands for *Type*. You can also encounter another convention called F, for *Fonction*, which is roughly the same. More details here: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appartement#Classification_des_logements

Comment: In the south of France we use T1, T2, altough people will usually understand F1, F2, etc.

I've found here a good description of all the subtleties one needs to know about all the different types :
http://www.partenaire-europeen.fr/Actualites-Conseils/Achat-Vente-entre-particuliers/Immobilier-entre-particuliers/lexique-immobilier-de-definition-des-pieces-20080904